# Moderator Election - We need more candidates!

Tags: discussion, election

In a bit over 3 hours, [the nomination phase of the moderator elections](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1) is scheduled to end. However, in order for the election to proceed, it is necessary to have at least one more candidate running than there are slots. This allows for there to be actual voting phases, so that the community can actually show that they support the candidates who are running. Should there not be enough candidates come 20:00 UTC when the phase change would occur, the nomination phase will instead be extended for another 7 days.

We need leadership to come from within this community, the election can't move forward unless someone wants to take on the responsibility. This is your graduation election - appointed pro tem moderators' terms automatically expire at the conclusion of voting, so we need to elect a full complement of moderators in this election. Did you consider nominating but decided not to for some reason? Now would be a great time to reconsider!

Comment: are the pro term moderators barred from nomination?

Comment: @oW_ They're not :)

Answer (score 5):

Some of our other top users would be welcome to nominate themselves!

https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users/836/neil-slater
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users/381/emre
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users/924/anony-mousse
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users/14904/jan-van-der-vegt
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users/8820/martin-thoma
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users/9420/an6u5
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users/548/indico

etc.

Comment: Why didn't you want to do it yourself?

Comment: I think I've done a lot of the moderation to date, and would like others to have the pleasure.

Comment: maybe you could share some of your (positive) experiences as a moderator and some info about the expected time commitment? it might convince some undecided people to nominate themselves...

Comment: Positive: I think that if you like the idea of contributing by voting on questions or triaging or reviewing the close queue, then it's a turbocharged way to do that. You have more scope to 'tend' the community directly. There's no minimum time commitment. I have tried to spend at least an hour a week moderating to keep up, so you could say that's about the time you'd need to contribute.