# We need at least one more candidate for the election to not get terminated

Tags: discussion, election

In accordance to Grace's [previous post](https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2298/11097), we need at least `n+1` candidates for a successful election, where `n` is the number of moderator slots available. In our case, it is `3`.

Currently, we have 3 candidates up for the nomination. There is still 6 hours left for the nomination. So, people who were interested in moderating the site, but were not sure, this is the time to throw in your hats.

As this is the postponed date, if there are not enough people up for the nomination, then the election would be terminated and would be left for the community to be decided.

We have been awesome together in bringing this site to the status of a graduated site. So, let's step up for moderating it, and making it more useful and helpful for fellow data science enthusiasts :)

Comment: Considering how weak the pool of candidates is (except you) I'd rather see this election terminated than having to choose 3 from there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the election is currently cancelled