# Criteria for Sheriff Badge?

Tags: bug, moderation, election

How is it possible that Dawny33 has been an elected moderator for a year when there has never been a moderator election?  Shouldn't this be the constable badge?

[image]

Comment: Weird.  Probably, it was because I was made mod after the site graduated from beta?  Anyways, we never had elected mods.  Let me take this up in the mods chat-room :)

Answer (score 2):

Hm, I don't quite recall, but didn't we have an election? or, at least we needed to add more mods. I recall there only being a few volunteers.

I would certainly favor another election, or really, just more mods. I am not sure how to ask for it?

Comment: The election was canceled since there were not enough candidates.  If it had not been canceled, you would not still be a mod, since you did not run. https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2309/community-moderator-election-has-been-cancelled?rq=1