# 2019 Potential Moderator Election Community Interest Check

Tags: discussion, moderation, election

As you might remember, around a year and a half ago, [this community's first election failed](https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2309/8879) — as this community's "fully graduated," elections are a vital part of the moderator selection process, as opposed to "Beta" sites' staff-picked pro-tem moderators. To add to that, since then the Community Team's noticed that the bulk of the flag handling's *still* been mostly done by a single moderator.

To avoid finding ourselves in a similar situation as our first attempt at an election for Data Science, I'm posting this to try to assess the community members' willingness to step up and nominate themselves, in a possibly upcoming election.

Please leave an answer if you'd be willing to run for a moderator position, should we decide to run an election. We're currently looking at starting question collection sometime in Feb./Mar. '19.

**NOTE:** This is not an official election nomination thread, just a "pulse check" to get a notion of how many people here would be willing to step up, so you don't have to put up your whole election nomination.

Comment: It may be worth clarifying that the current mods would have to run in the election if they want to keep the diamond... which, apparently, none of them want.

Comment: @user380 More than willing to continue being a mod here.  I'm waiting for more nominations :)  Last time election's failure was due to very less nominations

Comment: What are the requirements to be nominated as a moderator? Is there a reputation threshold or something else to decide who can participate and who cannot?

Comment: A minimum of 300 reputation points is required to be able to run, @bkshi.

Comment: Thanks for expressing interest, @Dawny33! We're scheduling the question collection for the election to start on March 18th :)

Comment: @JNat Is everything still on track for a 3/18 election start?

Comment: Yup, @I_Play_With_Data :)

Comment: Isn't this supposed to be today?

Comment: Yup! Posting the Meta post in a bit ;)

Answer (score 6):

I would be willing to run for a moderator position

Comment: Thanks for expressing interest! We're scheduling the question collection for the election to start on March 18th :)

Comment: @JNat thanks. I look forward to it.

Answer (score 5):

Count me in. I was waiting for the elections to step up :)

Comment: Thanks for expressing interest! We're scheduling the question collection for the election to start on March 18th :)

Comment: Sounds great! Cannot wait :)

Answer (score 4):

I would be willing to nominate myself as well

Comment: Thanks for expressing interest! We're scheduling the question collection for the election to start on March 18th :)

Answer (score 0):

I would be willing to run for moderator as well, to help alleviate some of the pressure off our existing 4 moderators.

I would like to run not because I consider myself an expert in ML, but because I  am frequently active, understand the platform guidelines to assist with question moderation, and would also like to help grow and develop the community for this site.